# Updated contact photo delete when gmail contact sync is performed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I am working on a android app, here i am updating the contact photo by using below code.

```
public void UpdateContact(String contactId,ContentResolver resolver){

     int rawContactId = -1;

     Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                                    new String[] {contactId}, null);

     if(cursor.moveToFirst())
     {
         rawContactId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));

         if(rawContactId > -1)
         {               
             ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

              ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)                         
                         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
                         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,Converttobytes("/sdcard/photos/456.jpg", true))
                         .build());   

             try    
             {   
                 resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);   
             } catch (RemoteException e) {

             } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
     cursor.close();        
}
```

Photo is updated when i sync with gmail previous contact photo updated back, but recently modified in mobile app so mobile app data should update to gmail contacts.

anything wrong in above code or any suggestion to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: any can respond please...

Comment: did you find any solution ? Actually I am working on similar type of concept in which i am performing contact sync and I want to get updated contact, could be please help me if you have done this...